# Selective contacts on iphone

Tags: contacts, gmail

I've synced my google (gmail) contacts to my iphone5, but i'd like to have some contacts not show on my phone.  Is there a way to select either on the phone or on gmail which contacts to show on my phone?

Answer (score 1):

iOS will show all contacts under "My contacts" on Google / Gmail.
If you move contacts out of that group, they will not show on your iPhone.

To do that, go to http://gmail.com and login with your credentials.
Click on `Mail`on the top left and select `Contacts`.

[image: Mail, Contacts, Tasks menu on Gmail]

There you can see which contacts are on which groups and move the contacts you'd like to hide from iOS (and OS X, by the way) out of "My contacts".

This has even helped me when deleting contacts by mistake, as they don't dissapear from your Google account, they just get moved to "Other contacts".

You can group them if you like but those groups will not be available or selectable for display / hide on your iPhone on the standard configuration. When you have multiple contacts lists from different accounts, a `Groups` option appears on the top left menu on the Contacts app, and Google Apps may show `Address Book` and `Global Address Book` as options, but the latter will take you to an empty list designed to search from the organization list of addresses. Or –as of right now on my iPhone after showing me those options– it may show you only one option per account (`All (name-of-the-account)`), to toggle on or off.

[image: group selection on the Contacts app (in Spanish, my bad)]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's a perfect answer, but could you place the contacts into 2 different groups, and then only display the group you want to see (I think they will both be on the phone, but just not shown).
At the top left of the "contacts" screen on the phone, you can select Groups, and turn them on and off there.

Answer (score 0):

Jaime Santa Cruz's answer should work perfectly.  I just want to add that if you did all that but still see unwanted contacts, you may have to force iOS to refresh the Contacts.  To do so, goto your iPhone's Settings and select Mail , Contacts, Calendars. Select Gmail, uncheck Contacts and then recheck Contacts.  When you go back to the Contacts app, it should work.